# Append Excel Files in Multiple Directories in Python

Tags: python, excel, operating-system, nested-loops

My goal is to append 9 excel files together that exist in different directories. I have a directory tree with the following structure:

```
Big Folder
|
├── folder_1/
|   ├── file1.xls
|   ├── file2.xls
|   └── file3.xls
|
├── folder_2/
|   ├── file4.xls
|   ├── file5.xls
|   └── file6.xls
|
├── folder_3/
|   ├── file7.xls
|   ├── file8.xls
|   └── file9.xls
```

I successfully wrote a loop that appends `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` together within `folder_1`. My idea is to nest this loop into another loop that flows through each folder as a list. I'm currently tring to us `os.walk` to accomplish this but am running into the following error in `folder_1`

> [Errno 2 No such file or directory]

Do community members have recommendations on how to extend this loop to execute in each directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to know how you have implemented the program without given some sort of code to work with, however I believe you have misused the `os.walk()` method, please read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

I would use the `os.walk()` method the following way for getting the path to various files in a current directory and subdirectories.

```
import os    
all_files = [(path, files) for path, dirs, files in os.walk(".")]
```

and then get all the files which ends with "*.xls" like so

```
all_xls_files = [
    os.path.join(path, xls_file)
    for (path, xls_files_list) in all_files
    for xls_file in xls_files_list
    if xls_file.endswith(".xls")
]
```

this is equivalent to

```
all_xls_files = []
for (path, xls_files_list) in all_files:
    for xls_file in xls_files_list:
        if xls_file.endswith(".xls"):
            files.append(os.path.join(path, xls_file))
```

Once you obtain a list of excel files with their path
you can open them by

```
with open("my_output_file", "w") as output_file:
    for file in all_xls_files:
        with open(file) as f:
            # Do your append here
```